# \s+ not matching all whitespaces?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match this string:

> Text 18 19 Text

With this regex:

```
\s+\d\d\s+
```

The string has two digits, each of them are surrounded by a leading and a trailing space.

So I'm thinking - this should give me 18 and 19 right?
It doesn't, it only gives me only 18.

I'm testing with this tester here: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you do not match the second item is that the space between `18` and `19` is *consumed* by the trailing `\s+` of the first match. You should make a non-consuming zero-width regexp for the trailing blank, for example by using the *lookahead syntax* or a token for zero-width boundary:

```
\s+\d\d(?=\s+)
```

Comment: Nice explaination +1 for the post.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
\b\d\d\b
```

Your regex isn't matching the second number because the first match has already "eaten up" all the spaces.

Meanwhile, `\b` is a "word boundary," and what is known as a zero-width (meta-)character: it doesn't "eat up" anything while it matches.

Comment: Awesome. I'm curious though, why does \b not eat up the spaces whereas \s does?

Comment: @David - See edit. It's one of several regex constructs that are designed to be zero-width. Another notable one would be lookaheads, which you could have used as well: `\s+\d\d(?=\s)`.

Comment: beware that this would also capture the two digit at the end if there is any

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It - Yes, `\b\d\d\b` would capture at the end, as well as the beginning, which I imagine is a good thing. On the other hand, `\s+\d\d(?=\s)` would fail to capture two digits at the beginning or end, which is probably not intended.

Answer (score 3):

Because first parsing outputs to " 18 " and remaining string is "19 Text" which is not a match.